# Lagrangian Equation

Tags: classical-mechanics

A hoop with radius r is rolling, without slipping, down an inclined plane
of length l and with angle of inclination 'a'. Assign appropriate
generalized coordinates to the system. Determine the constraints, if any.
Write down the Lagrangian equations for the system. Hence or
otherwise determine the velocity of the hoop at the bottom of the
inclined plane.

Comment: That's just the statement of a problem. Could you provide what you have tried?

Comment: I could not assume how to begin with the problem.

Comment: Then you should specify what is precisely your question. Do you know the Euler-Lagrange equation? Can you obtain the kinetic and potential energy of the hoop? Can you choose a simple set of coordinates?

Comment: Actually my problem lies in first part,i.e. to assign generalized coordinates

Comment: Ok, fine. How many coordinates do you think that you will need to describe the movement of the hoop?

Comment: I think it's three.

Answer (score 2):

Define the generalized coordinates $\theta$ and $x$ as the hoop angular displacement (rotation) and the linear displacement along the plane, respectively, with $x$ pointing downward.

See that, since the hoop can't slip, the tangential velocity of the hoop in contact to the plane must be equal to the plane velocity, i.e., 0. Therefore, the "forward" velocity of the hoop $\dot{x}$ must be equal to the "backward" velocity $r \dot{\theta}$. Then, you have the constraint $\dot{x} = r \dot{\theta}$, that ensure that the hoop is rolling, not slipping.

The kinetic energy of the hoop is given by the sum of the kinetic energy of each "kind" of motion:
$$
T = \frac{1}{2} m \dot{x}^2 + \frac{1}{2} J \dot{\theta}^2
$$
The first term corresponds to the energy of the linear movement ($m$ being the mass) and the second term to the angular movement ($J$ is the moment of inertia).

The potential energy is simply
$$
V = -mgx \sin a.
$$
Therefore, the Lagrangian is $L = T-V$, or
$$
L = \frac{1}{2} m \dot{x}^2 + \frac{1}{2} J \dot{\theta}^2 + mgx \sin a.
$$
Introducing the constraint $\dot{x} = r \dot{\theta}$,
$$
L = \frac{1}{2} m \dot{x}^2 + \frac{1}{2} \frac{J}{r^2} \dot{x}^2 + mgx \sin a.
$$

From the Lagrange equation, that, for our case, is
$$
\frac{d}{dt} \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{x}} - \frac{\partial L}{\partial x} = 0,
$$
we have
$$
\left( m + \frac{J}{r^2} \right) \ddot{x} + mg\sin a = 0.
$$

We can obtain the final velocity of the hoop through the solution of this equation, but we can use the conservation of the total energy $E = T+V$ instead. See that
$$
T = \left( m + \frac{J}{r^2} \right) \frac{\dot{x}^2}{2},
$$
then the quantity
$$
E = \left( m + \frac{J}{r^2} \right) \frac{\dot{x}^2}{2} - mgx\sin a
$$
is constant for all the trajectory. In the initial condition, $x = 0$ and $\dot{x} = v_0$, then
$$
E = \left( m + \frac{J}{r^2} \right) \frac{v_0^2}{2}.
$$
In the end of the plane, $x=l$ and $\dot{x} = v_{end}$. Then,
$$
E = \left( m + \frac{J}{r^2} \right) \frac{v_0^2}{2} = \left( m + \frac{J}{r^2} \right) \frac{v_{end}^2}{2} - mgl\sin a
$$
$$
v_{end}^2 = v_0^2 + 2\left( 1 + \frac{J}{r^2m} \right)^{-1} gl\sin a
$$
The moment of inertia of a hoop is $r^2m$, therefore,

$$
v_{end} = \sqrt{v_0^2 + gl\sin a}
$$

Comment: The potential energy must be V = $ mg(l-x) \sin a $ and consequently $ v_{end} = \sqrt{v_0^2 + gl\sin a} $

Comment: For whatever reason, I decided that the length of the plane was $1$ (maybe I misread your post). So you are right about the final expression; mine lacks the $l$. Regarding the potential energy, it doesn't make any difference. Your referential is the bottom of the plane (where $V=0$). Mine is at the top. Since we are adding a constant to $V$ (and to $E$), it doesn't change anything.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying my doubt. There's another thing I would like to know that should the potential energy V have a component $mgr cos a$ which is the height of centre of hoop from inclined plane.